# Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string[]'?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have to count the row on table. Based on that count I have to Assign Team. While using the given below code showing an error Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'string[]'.

Code:

```
protected void ddlCircle_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ArrayList teamList = new ArrayList();

      ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_CadEngineersTeamTableAdapter cd;
      cd = new ShadingAnalysisDataSetTableAdapters.tbl_CadEngineersTeamTableAdapter();
      DataTable dt = new DataTable();
      dt = cd.GetAvailableData(ddlCircle.SelectedValue);

      int x;

      x = dt.Rows.Count;

      String[] a;


      for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
        {
           a = teamList.Add(String.Format("Team{0}", i)); // error popup here
        }
    }
```

Comment: Aside from anything else, why are you still using `ArrayList`?

Comment: `a` is a string array. `ArrayList.Add` returns `int`. You can't assign an integer to string array. I think you want this as `a[i]`. And don't use `ArrayList` anymore. It belongs the old days that C# doesn't have Generics. Use `List<T>` instead.

Comment: And why are you *trying* to assign to `a`? What do you expect that to achieve?

Comment: What's the return type of the teamList.Add()-method?

Comment: [`ArrayList.Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.add(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the index of the new item added. You are assigning that `int` to a `string[]` which doesn't compile. _"I have to count the row on table"_ What do you actually want to count since you've already the row-count(`int x = dt.Rows.Count;`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The returned value type of `Add()` method is  `int`, and you are assigning it to `string[]` array. Change your code to:

```
  for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
       teamList.Add(String.Format("Team{0}", i));
    }
```

Also if you want to convert ArrayList to string[], you can use following code:

```
  a = teamList.ToArray(typeof(string)) as string[];
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would change teamList to something like this...

```
var teamList = new List<string>();
```

and then when it comes to populating the List do this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++)
    {
      teamList.Add(string.Format("Team{0}",i));
    }
```

Then once the loop is finished you can just call:

```
a = teamList.ToArray()
```

and then your string array will be teamList in array form.

Is there a specific reason you would need to asign it to that array and could not just pass the list out?